# Apache Spark error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-32.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\rt.jar;F:\IJ\scatest\aas-master\ch02-intro\target\classes;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.cloudera.datascience.intro.RunIntro
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:125)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 6 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I searched the specified directory and the "RDD.scala" file is present.

Comment: Looks like an issue with classpath. Check if it contains spark lib.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the classPath you have mentioned I assume that your trying out the example from https://github.com/sryza/aas.

You haven't imported the project properly on your IDE. you can run the same code from the command line using maven.

```
#run this from the respective module's directory
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.cloudera.datascience.intro.RunIntro"
```

Note : While importing the project select on the parent `pom.xml` file. Intellij will resolve all the dependencies by itself.

Alternatively you can add the jars manually by following [Correct way to add external jars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32853178/2104970)

Comment: I tried it. Doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Did you run this from the module's directory ? I've modified my answer i accidentally mentioned the parent directory. I have the same repo locally and its working.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that you have imported the project as a sbt project. 
You have to import the project as a maven project , and then run it !

You can do this by installing the Maven plugin and then re-import the project as a maven project and then run it. I hope that helps !